# Can I make a "fallback" serializer in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I would like to create a Jackson custom serializer that works on all POJOs *unless* there exists a built-in Jackson serializer for it. For example, instances of Float or String would be handled by Jackson but some other POJO would be handled by me.

I tried adding a custom serializer for Object.class but seems to override the built-in Jackson ones. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature currently; but you might be able to do this by sub-classing `BeanDeserializerFactory`, as it does first check for explicit deserializers before trying to construct a `BeanDeserializer`.